# Python and PyQt5 video in child window wont display

Tags: python, opencv, pyqt5

I am trying to create a gui, where there is a main window which contains 3 buttons, 1st cam , 2nd cam and 3rd cam.

Currently it runs without error and when you click 1st cam it does open a window and its blank, if you click the button again it hides.  This works for all 3 buttons.  However the video does not display in the boxes that it loads.

```
import sys
from random import randint
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QTextEdit, QAction, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer, QPoint, pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont, QPainter, QImage, QTextCursor

import cv2
import queue as Queue

IMG_SIZE    = 640,480          # 640,480 or 1280,720 or 1920,1080
IMG_FORMAT  = QImage.Format_RGB888
DISP_SCALE  = 2                # Scaling factor for display image
DISP_MSEC   = 50                # Delay between display cycles
CAP_API     = cv2.CAP_ANY       # API: CAP_ANY or CAP_DSHOW etc...
EXPOSURE    = 0                 # Zero for automatic exposure
TEXT_FONT   = QFont("Courier", 10)

camera_num  = 1                 # Default camera (first in list)
image_queue = Queue.Queue()     # Queue to hold images
capturing   = True              # Flag to indicate capturing

# Grab images from the camera (separate thread)
def grab_images(cam_num, queue):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(cam_num-1 + CAP_API)
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, IMG_SIZE[0])
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, IMG_SIZE[1])
    if EXPOSURE:
        cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_AUTO_EXPOSURE, 0)
        cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE, EXPOSURE)
    else:
        cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_AUTO_EXPOSURE, 1)
    while capturing:
        if cap.grab():
            retval, image = cap.retrieve(0)
            if image is not None and queue.qsize() < 2:
                queue.put(image)
            else:
                time.sleep(DISP_MSEC / 1000.0)
        else:
            print("Error: can't grab camera image")
            break
    cap.release()


class CamStream(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        #this is the individual windows and hopefully camera feed screens
        super().__init__()
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.label = QLabel("DISPLAY % d" % randint(0, 100))
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.setGeometry(10, 10, 640, 480)
        ##### webcam code starts here
        DISP_SCALE  = 1                 # Scaling factor for display image
 
    # Start image capture & display
    def start(self):
        self.timer = QTimer(self)           # Timer to trigger display
        self.timer.timeout.connect(lambda: 
                    self.show_image(image_queue, self.disp, DISP_SCALE))
        self.timer.start(DISP_MSEC)         
        self.capture_thread = threading.Thread(target=grab_images, 
                    args=(camera_num, image_queue))
        self.capture_thread.start()         # Thread to grab images
 
    # Fetch camera image from queue, and display it
    def show_image(self, imageq, display, scale):
        if not imageq.empty():
            image = imageq.get()
            if image is not None and len(image) > 0:
                img = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                self.display_image(img, display, scale)
 
    # Display an image, reduce size if required
    def display_image(self, img, display, scale=1):
        disp_size = img.shape[1]//scale, img.shape[0]//scale
        disp_bpl = disp_size[0] * 3
        if scale > 1:
            img = cv2.resize(img, disp_size, interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
        qimg = QImage(img.data, disp_size[0], disp_size[1], disp_bpl, IMG_FORMAT)
        display.setImage(qimg)
        ###webcam code ends here
        self.setLayout(layout)
    
        # Window is closing: stop video capture
    def closeEvent(self, event):
        global capturing
        capturing = False
        self.capture_thread.join()


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        #this is for main background screen
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(10, 10, 1920, 1080)
        self.window1 = CamStream()
        self.window2 = CamStream()
        self.window3 = CamStream()

        l = QVBoxLayout()
        
        button1 = QPushButton("Main CAM")
        button1.clicked.connect(
            lambda checked: self.toggle_window(self.window1)
        )
        l.addWidget(button1)

        button2 = QPushButton("Second CAM")
        button2.clicked.connect(
            lambda checked: self.toggle_window(self.window2)
        )
        l.addWidget(button2)
        
        button3 = QPushButton("Third CAM")
        button3.clicked.connect(
            lambda checked: self.toggle_window(self.window3)
        )
        l.addWidget(button3)

        w = QWidget()
        w.setLayout(l)
        self.setCentralWidget(w)

    def toggle_window(self, window):
        if window.isVisible():
            window.hide()

        else:
            window.show()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = MainWindow()
w.show()
app.exec()
```

Why is it not drawing the video in the windows?

I did this code, and this creates a window with a video, but it didn't work with using the large main empty window.

```
Screen_Title = "CAM Selection"

import sys, time, threading, cv2
try:
    from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
    pyqt5 = True
except:
    pyqt5 = False
if pyqt5:
    from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer, QPoint, pyqtSignal
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QTextEdit, QLabel
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QAction, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout
    from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont, QPainter, QImage, QTextCursor
else:
    from PyQt4.QtCore import Qt, pyqtSignal, QTimer, QPoint
    from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QMainWindow, QTextEdit, QLabel
    from PyQt4.QtGui import QWidget, QAction, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout
    from PyQt4.QtGui import QFont, QPainter, QImage, QTextCursor
try:
    import Queue as Queue
except:
    import queue as Queue

IMG_SIZE    = 1280,720          # 640,480 or 1280,720 or 1920,1080
IMG_FORMAT  = QImage.Format_RGB888
DISP_SCALE  = 2                # Scaling factor for display image
DISP_MSEC   = 50                # Delay between display cycles
CAP_API     = cv2.CAP_ANY       # API: CAP_ANY or CAP_DSHOW etc...
EXPOSURE    = 0                 # Zero for automatic exposure


camera_num  = 1                 # Default camera (first in list)
image_queue = Queue.Queue()     # Queue to hold images
capturing   = True              # Flag to indicate capturing

# Grab images from the camera (separate thread)
def grab_images(cam_num, queue):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(cam_num-1 + CAP_API)
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, IMG_SIZE[0])
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, IMG_SIZE[1])
    if EXPOSURE:
        cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_AUTO_EXPOSURE, 0)
        cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE, EXPOSURE)
    else:
        cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_AUTO_EXPOSURE, 1)
    while capturing:
        if cap.grab():
            retval, image = cap.retrieve(0)
            if image is not None and queue.qsize() < 2:
                queue.put(image)
            else:
                time.sleep(DISP_MSEC / 1000.0)
        else:
            print("Error: can't grab camera image")
            break
    cap.release()

# Image widget
class ImageWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ImageWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.image = None

    def setImage(self, image):
        self.image = image
        self.setMinimumSize(image.size())
        self.update()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QPainter()
        qp.begin(self)
        if self.image:
            qp.drawImage(QPoint(0, 0), self.image)
        qp.end()

# Main window
class MyWindow(QMainWindow):
    text_update = pyqtSignal(str)

    # Create main window
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)

        self.setMinimumSize(640, 360) #set size of window wrapping video


        self.vlayout = QVBoxLayout()        # Window layout
        self.displays = QHBoxLayout()
        self.disp = ImageWidget(self)    
        self.displays.addWidget(self.disp)
        self.vlayout.addLayout(self.displays)
        self.label = QLabel(self)
        self.vlayout.addWidget(self.label)


    # Start image capture & display
    def start(self):
        self.timer = QTimer(self)           # Timer to trigger display
        self.timer.timeout.connect(lambda: 
                    self.show_image(image_queue, self.disp, DISP_SCALE))
        self.timer.start(DISP_MSEC)         
        self.capture_thread = threading.Thread(target=grab_images, 
                    args=(camera_num, image_queue))
        self.capture_thread.start()         # Thread to grab images

    # Fetch camera image from queue, and display it
    def show_image(self, imageq, display, scale):
        if not imageq.empty():
            image = imageq.get()
            if image is not None and len(image) > 0:
                img = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                self.display_image(img, display, scale)

    # Display an image, reduce size if required
    def display_image(self, img, display, scale=1):
        disp_size = img.shape[1]//scale, img.shape[0]//scale
        disp_bpl = disp_size[0] * 3
        if scale > 1:
            img = cv2.resize(img, disp_size, 
                             interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
        qimg = QImage(img.data, disp_size[0], disp_size[1], 
                      disp_bpl, IMG_FORMAT)
        display.setImage(qimg)

    # Handle sys.stdout.write: update text display
    def write(self, text):
        self.text_update.emit(str(text))
    def flush(self):
        pass

    # Window is closing: stop video capture
    def closeEvent(self, event):
        global capturing
        capturing = False
        self.capture_thread.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        try:
            camera_num = int(sys.argv[1])
        except:
            camera_num = 0
    if camera_num < 1:
        print("Invalid camera number '%s'" % sys.argv[1])
    else:
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        win = MyWindow()
        win.show()
        win.setWindowTitle(Screen_Title)
        win.start()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: You're not calling `window.start()`. You should also move `self.setLayout(layout)` into the `__init__`.

Comment: @musicamante, thank you for replying but I'm not sure if I have been looking at it to long, but start is called as it will open the main window, provide me with the 3 buttons, when I click the buttons it does open the window, just not the camera feed.  I don't see where I missed the ```window.start()```

Comment: The "start" you're referring to is *not* `start`, it's what shows the main window. I'm talking about the method in each `CamStream` class, which is the one that *actually* starts the video feed, and you're not calling anywhere in your first code.

Comment: @musicamante the ```CamStream```  created in the click button, to start, so it opens as the window opens does it not?  mind providing a a snippet? I don't know if it's cause I'm tired or if I'm just not seeing it.

Comment: If you're tired, don't keep banging your head on it. "Show" and "start" are two distinct concepts. Your "start" in the above comments is about showing the interface, I'm talking about the *method* **named** `start`, which is **never** called in your first script.